# Android snackbar over drawerlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-snackbar

I have a snackbar (on a RecyclerView) and a DrawerLayout. When the snackbar is shown and I open the drawerlayout, the snackbar overlaps the drawer. I want the drawer to overlap the snackbar. Is this possible?

```
Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, R.string.something, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for `Snackbar.make`:

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent, which is defined as a CoordinatorLayout or the window decor's content view, whichever comes first.

Wrap your RecyclerView in a CoordinatorLayout.